# Angular2 UI framework for web & mobile

Tags: user-interface, angular, frameworks

I'm planning to start a new angular2 project using UI frameworks which support both WEB & Mobile, i have searched few things and found these:

> https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap
>   https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/core
>   https://github.com/mlaval/angular2-bootstrap 
>   http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete

I saw Ionic seems to better, but they primarily support only for the mobile. Do you have any suggestions for the UI framework for Web and mobile which supports Angular2

Thanks

Comment: `https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` may be one which you know already so  will be easy Primeng is paid and need to learn

Comment: oh, in their site, they had mentioned as free for use. "PrimeNG is a collection of rich UI components for Angular 2. PrimeNG is a sibling of the popular JavaServer Faces Component Suite, PrimeFaces. All widgets are open source and free to use under MIT License."

Comment: but not commonly known :)

Comment: PrimeNG is very popular in Angular 2 world actually with thousands of users in community. It has a bootstrap theme and material theme as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Bootstrap` is something which many developers are familiar and and `primeNG`  needs to be implemented through learning neew things, too and talking about ionic you need lot much more to know than only HTML,CSS stuff so If you want `HTML site which works with mobile browser` go for Bootstrap and if you need mobile `Application` with webpage you need to look into other frameworks like `ionic`.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that the angular material 2 is the best framework. Currently, it is in beta 1 but it has many components with which you can start the project. You can follow up the progress on their github. The main advantage is that its built by angular team.

https://github.com/angular/material2

https://material.angular.io/